# How to get activity finish call back?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a view that is starting a Dialer Activity via:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

I want to have a `callback` when the user moves away from the dialer activity. I can't touch dialer activity so I can't override its `onPause()` method. The `onActivityResult` won't work either as it won't get called when the user navigates away from the dialer via `HOME` or `RECENTS` button.

Can I override the Dialer activity that android provides to changes its `onPause()` method ?

Comment: What do you want to do by getting call back..What is your purpose?

Comment: Jeep, please discribe what you want to achief, maybe it could be solved with startActivityForResult

Answer (score 1):

OK, then start the intent with:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
 startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_DIAL);
```

Then Override OnActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //if the RequestCode = RESULT_DIAL then do waht you want
  }
```

Comment: Does onActivityResult gets called when the user navigates away from the dialer using `HOME` or `RECENTS` button ?

Comment: I strongly think so, just tryed the BackButton, but Home should work too